# rDNS and forward DNS for mail server behind firewall, different IPs

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, email-server, router, reverse-dns

All,

Here is my setup :

Firewall(x.x.x.114) <--> mail.mailserver.com (FQDN) (x.x.x.118)

When sending mail, header has following IP ...."Receivedfrom mail.mailserver.com ([x.x.x.114])", my forward DNS for domain foo.com that is sending the email has IP of x.x.x.118 , also mail.mailserver.com has A record of x.x.x.118. HELO record has client IP of x.x.x.114 and server as mail.mailserver.com (domain in this case shouldn't matter as we are checking received IP to that rDNS of mailserver)

We set the PTR record for mail.mailserver.com as x.x.x.114 thinking since receiving mail server sees IP of firewall rather than actual mailserver IP. However when it does compare with forward DNS, it obviously resolves to x.x.x.118 but reverse has been set to x.x.x.114. This will cause mails to be rejected by some servers ... how to solve this problem...

Comment: It looks like your firewall is also Nat'ing the mailserver. Does the mailserver have the public ip  118 assigned to a nic?

Comment: Hi Michael,  Not really, no public IP assigned to the mail server... FW routes it to local IP address. Essentially have /8 IP range assigned to us, 114 is for the router ... but since 118 falls in range , we use that to run mail server services as far as outside world is concerned. Then inbound rules translate that to lan IP

Comment: Ok, so on the config of your firewall (make and model would help?) you have given the outside (WAN) connection the IP ending 114 and have also added 118 as an ip alias/object. Any traffic being sent to 118 is then sent to the LAN ip that is assigned to the mailserver. Is that about right?

Comment: Hi, it is FVS318G from netgear ...You got it, that is how it is configured. We didnot want to expose mailserver directly for multitude of reasons.

Comment: No that is fine, I've not used that firewall before but on netgears there is normally a screen for outbound rules. You need to make an outbound rule . Lan User (LAN IP of mailserver) Wan User (Any) NAT IP (Enter the 118 address). You can test it by going to http://whatismyip.org/ from the mailserver. This should show you the 118 address.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This has really helped. I still have to test it later in evening. So I will reset the PTR back to 118 if this passes and HELO will now show correct IP right ?

Comment: If it works then yes reset everything to point back to 118. Let me know and I'll post the solution out as the answer

Comment: Sure, might be few 3 hrs from now... Thanks again.

Comment: Works ... tested by sending email .... proper IP, SPF passes everything is good, now to change the rDNS, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in the comments, but posting out as the answer

I've not used that firewall before but on netgears there is normally a screen for outbound rules. You need to make an outbound rule . Lan User (LAN IP of mailserver) Wan User (Any) NAT IP (Enter the 118 address).

Effectively what has been done is to create an outbound Nat on the firewall. So outbound traffic appears to come from the 118 address.